# How can I change the .innerHTML property of an appended button text using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a "Like" button for a post which was fetched by AJAX using jQuery. Here, I want to change button text while clicked. But it's not changing.

Here is my Like button codes:

```
$('.posted-area').append('\
  <div class="posted-footer">\
    <ul>\
      <li>\
        <button class="btnLike btn-danger" id="btnLike" onclick="btnLikefunction()"> Like </button>\
      </li>\
      <li>\
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i> </a>\
          <span>15 comments</span>\
      </li>\                         
    </ul>\
  </div>\
');
```

Here is my `onClick` event for the "Like" button:

```
function btnLikefunction(){
   var btnTextChange = document.getElementById(".btnLike");
   btnTextChange.innerHTML= "Liked!";
}
```

Comment: `.btnLike` isn’t an ID; `btnLike` is an ID. Please also see [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](/q/203198/4642212).

Comment: Are you adding multiple `<div class="posted-footer">` items to the DOM? If so, each must have a unique ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need 2 changes

```
onclick="btnLikefunction(this)"
```

and

```
function btnLikefunction(elm) {
  $(elm).text("Liked").css('color', 'red'); // set text and color
}
```

**Example**

```js
$('.posted-area').append('\
                   <div class="posted-footer">\
                       <ul>\
                            <li>\
                             <button class="btnLike btn-danger" id="btnLike" onclick="btnLikefunction(this)"> Like </button>\
                           </li>\
                            <li>\
                             <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i> </a>\
                             <span>15 comments</span>\
                           </li>\ </ul>\ </div>\
    ');


function btnLikefunction(elm) {
  $(elm).text("Liked").css('color', 'red'); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="posted-area"></div>
```

Comment: can you solve? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74273741/how-can-i-show-user-has-liked-post-as-facebook-style-in-jquery-ajax-laravel

Answer (score 0):

```js
let html = $(`<div class="posted-footer">
                       <ul>
                            <li>
                             <button class="btnLike btn-danger" id="btnLike"> Like </button>
                           </li>
                            <li>
                             <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i> </a>
                             <span>15 comments</span>
                           </li>                        
                       </ul>
                   </div>
                   `)

html.appendTo('#post-wrapper')
html.find(".btnLike").on("click",e=>{
  $(e.target).html("Liked!")
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="post-wrapper"></div>
```

This is method is to use jquery to wrap your html first, then you can use jquery event listener `on` on the html.

---

Problem with your code is you use the wrong JS selector, where you use select by ID function but you pass a class name into it, since you are using jquery, you can change from:

```
var btnTextChange = document.getElementById(".btnLike");
btnTextChange .innerHTML= "Liked!";
```

to

```
$(".btnLike").html("Liked!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. Find your button inside appended div and change your text.

Working Example:

```js
$('.posted-area').append('\
                   <div class="posted-footer">\
                       <ul>\
                            <li>\
                             <button class="btnLike btn-danger" id="btnLike" onclick="btnLikefunction()"> Like </button>\
                           </li>\
                            <li>\
                             <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i> </a>\
                             <span>15 comments</span>\
                           </li>\ </ul>\ </div>\
    ');


function btnLikefunction() {
  var btnTextChange = $(".posted-area").find(".btnLike")
  $(btnTextChange).addClass("red");
  $(btnTextChange).html("Liked!")
}
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="posted-area"></div>
```

To change text color you can use `addClass` like above example.

<sub>Note: Don't mismatch JavaScript and jQuery.</sub>

Comment: its working. can you tell me how can I change texts color?